# GCP Requests can't be forwarded to peer network because the peer project disabled DNS peering

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform

I just created a public DNS zone in GCP, everything works fine except, when I go into network details I see following message "Requests can't be forwarded to peer network because the peer project disabled DNS peering"

What does it mean?

Comment: What is the "DNS server policy" for both peered networks?

Comment: There are no DNS policies in the project.

Comment: I'm getting this message on my domains hosted in Google Cloud DNS as well. It doesn't seem to impact the operational nature of the domains. Hopefully GCP tech support has something useful to say about it?

Comment: This appeared for me as well this morning. Although everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 11):

It's a known issue and Google is looking into it... however, it might not get fixed since it is "just a aesthetics issue"

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128510674

Comment: Thank you! I just noticed the same issue on my end as well.